# Do we really need a [custom] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just stumbled over the tag [custom](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/custom). It currently has 41 questions, which have little in common. Some could be retagged to [customization](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/customization), when the goal of the question is to actually customize something. For example [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/248013/lamp-custom-500-error-page-is-it-actually-possible) or [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/327047/load-all-printers-drivers-on-a-custom-debian-cd), but even these two questions are so fundamentally different that I hesitate to use the same tag for both.

What would be the best course of action?

- burninate the tag, because it's ambigous
- retag questions with more specific tags (`custom-x`, `custom-y`,`custom-...`)
- keep it, but make sure it is used along with related tags that emphasize what should be customized

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tag [custom](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/custom) serves no purpose. No one follows it, and no one is likely to use it to find questions of interest. It should be burninated and blacklisted.

For that matter, the [customization](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/customization) tag looks equally useless.

Feel free to remove the tag from any such question you come across, and to replace it with another tag if a more appropriate one exists.

Comment: I've burninated the customization tag. The custom tag will come later. But feel free to knock out a few of them if you're reading this.

Comment: And the custom tag is gone as well (for now).

Comment: Should this get marked `status-completed`?